# Setting dynamic data to Radial Gauge

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am developing a Radial Gauge and I need to add dynamic data to it. The following is the code that i have done with dynamic data. Can some one help me with it to add dynamic data. My code example is given below.

```js
 var arrGauge_360 = [
    {key:"data-type",value:"radial-gauge"},
    {key:"data-width",value:"400"},
    {key:"data-height",value:"400"},
    {key:"data-max-value",value:"100"},
    {key:"data-value",value:"50"}, //this value has to be dynamic. not a static data. 
    {key:"data-animate-on-init",value:"true"},
    {key:"data-major-ticks",value:"0,20,40,60,80,100"},
 ];

 function myFunction_gauge_360(){
    debugger
    $("#gauge_360").append("<canvas id='ht_gauge_360'></canvas>");
    arrGauge_360.forEach(function(item,index){
        debugger
       $("#ht_gauge_360").attr(item.key,item.value);
    });
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gauge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>    
    <script src="HKgauge.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="gauge_360">

        </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>

$(function(){
        myFunction_gauge_360("gauge_360",arrGauge_360);
})

</script>
</html>
```